# UTF-8 decoding doesn't decode special characters in python

Tags: python, replace, utf-8, decode

Hi I have the following data (abstracted) that comes from an API.

```
"Product" : "T\u00e1bua 21X40"
```

I'm using the following code to decode the data byte:

```
var = json.loads(cleanhtml(str(json.dumps(response.content.decode('utf-8')))))
```

The cleanhtml is a regex function that I've created to remove html tags from the returned data (It's working correctly). Although, `decode(utf-8)` is not removing characters like `\u00e1`. My expected output is:

```
"Product" : "Tábua 21X40"
```

I've tried to use `replace("\\u00e1", "á")` but with no success. How can I replace this type of character and what type of character is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u00e1` is another way of representing the `á` character when displaying the contents of a Python string.

If you open a Python interactive session and run `print({"Product" : "T\u00e1bua 21X40"})` you'll see output of `{'Product': 'Tábua 21X40'}`. The `\u00e1` doesn't exist in the string as those individual characters.

The `\u` escape sequence indicates that the following numbers specify a Unicode character.

Attempting to replace `\u00e1` with `á` won't achieve anything because that's what it already is. Additionally, `replace("\\u00e1", "á")` is attempting to replace the individual characters of a slash, a `u`, etc and, as mentioned, they don't actually exist in the string in that way.

If you explain the problem you're encountering further then we may be able to help more, but currently it sounds like the string has the correct content but is just being displayed differently than you expect.

Comment: I didn't know that. I found a solution that works that is use \\\\  before the character code, this works with replace, so `replace("\\\\u00e1", "á")` replaces `u00e1`  to `a`. Maybe the post should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

*what type of character is this*

Here

```
"Product" : "T\u00e1bua 21X40"
```

you might observe [`\u` escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code), it is followed by 4 hex digits: `00e1`, note that this is different *represenation* of same character, so

```
print("\u00e1" == "á")
```

output

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

These type of characters are called character entities. There are different types of entities and this is JSON entity. For demonstration, enter your string [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html) and click unescape.
For your question, if you are using python then you can solve the issue by importing json module. Then you have to decode it as follows.

```
import json

string = json.loads('"T\u00e1bua 21X40"')
print(string)
```